# What are some good Variable name suffixes for a boolean for an option that is "allowed" or enabled?

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm trying to come up with a good naming convention for boolean variables that indicate something is "allowed".

E.g.,
**WarningAllowed**  or **WarningEnabled** (means that we have turned on the option to give a warning).

*CodeComplete* has some suggestion for booleans (Has<>  Is<>) but those aren't applicable.

My ideas:

- <>Enabled
- <>Allowed
- Should<>
- Allow<>

Comment: Enabled is good - sometimes I put it together e.g isTrue isFalse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the prefix `Can` used in this context. For example:

- [`StackPanel.CanHorizontallyScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.canhorizontallyscroll.aspx)
- [`ReceiveActivity.CanCreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.receiveactivity.cancreateinstance.aspx)
- [`CanExecuteToolEventArgs.CanExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.interaction.canexecutetooleventargs.canexecute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I like this naming convention quite a bit because it abstracts away the reason for the value, be it *true* or *false*: The user of the API usually does not have to know whether a command is not eligible because it is forbidden or because it is impossible to execute. The result is the same: a greyed-out menu item/button/whatever.

This also allows the reason to change in future versions (e.g. if a `Can*` property returns *false* only when something is actually impossible at first, but in future versions, an access rights model is added, and from then on, the value of said `Can*` property also depends on the current access rights).

Comment: Maybe an alternative to Can is Will, to imply it WILL happen.

Comment: @ClayNichols: But then, "will" sounds a bit like something is bound to happen without any further action, whereas the `Can...` properties just express that something *can* happen *if* it gets called.